# sqlite3 limit with offset is not working in android

Tags: sqlite

```
select * from <table_name> limit 100 offset 200;
```

Expected result is it should return rows from 201 to 300. But in android it is returning rows from 2 to 101.

```
sqlite> create table test (id integer primary key autoincrement, name text);
sqlite> insert into test (name) values('a');
sqlite> insert into test (name) values('a');
sqlite> ...
sqlite> select * from test limit 10 offset 2;
2|a 3|a 4|a 5|a 6|a 7|a
sqlite> select * from test limit 10 offset 5;
2|a 3|a 4|a 5|a 6|a 7|a
sqlite> select * from test limit 2 offset 5;
2|a 3|a
sqlite> select * from test limit 5,3;
2|a 3|a 4|a

sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 2 OFFSET 5;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     14    0                    00               
1     Integer        2     1     0                    00               
2     Integer        5     2     0                    00               
3     MustBeInt      2     0     0                    00               
4     OffsetLimit    1     3     2                    00               
5     OpenRead       0     383   0     2              00               
6     Rewind         0     13    0                    00               
7       IfPos          2     12    1                    00               
8       Rowid          0     4     0                    00               
9       Column         0     1     5                    00               
10      ResultRow      4     2     0                    00               
11      DecrJumpZero   1     13    0                    00               
12    Next           0     7     0                    01               
13    Halt           0     0     0                    00               
14    Transaction    0     0     44    0              01               
15    Goto           0     1     0                    00               
sqlite>

sqlite> .schema test
CREATE TABLE test (id integer primary key autoincrement, name text);

sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(test);          
0|id|integer|0||1
1|name|text|0||0
sqlite>
```

Do we need to enable any flags while compiling sqlite3 for android ?

Comment: This should work. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have taken the sqlite source code from https://www.sqlite.org/index.html and compiled for android. To reproduce this issue, Create a table with integer column and make it as primary key with autoincrement, then insert 500 records and then execute "select * from <table_name> limit 100 offset 200; " query.

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4d97d/1). Please show how exactly you are executing the query.

Comment: I am using sqlite version 3.23.1, I have taken the source code from https://www.sqlite.org/index.html. Which version are you using ?

Comment: Please show how exactly you are executing the query.

Comment: sqlite> create table test (id integer primary key autoincrement, name text);
sqlite> insert into test (name) values('a'); 
sqlite> insert into test (name) values('a');
sqlite> select * from test limit 10 offset 2;
2|a
3|a
4|a
5|a
6|a
7|a
sqlite> select * from test limit 10 offset 5;
2|a
3|a
4|a
5|a
6|a
7|a
sqlite> select * from test limit 2 offset 5;         
2|a
3|a
sqlite> select * from test limit 5,3;
2|a
3|a
4|a

Comment: Is that the `sqlite3` command-line shell that you have compiled yourself? Please edit the question to show the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 2 OFFSET 5;`.

Comment: Yes, i have compiled using the steps given in https://github.com/stockrt/sqlite3-android.

Comment: This is not an empty test database. Show the table definition and any indexes on this table.

Comment: Further update on this issue.

    I am observing this issue only with the library build using ndk-build via terminal and the library built via android studio gradle works fine. Is there any difference in compiling sqlite using gradle and via ndk-build via terminal ?